# Simple UI issue in winforms

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a simple winforms application, on performing operations it shows a child window everytime. If I open a browser window (fully maximized) or some other window as usual
the application goes back with its childwindow, on clicking the exe which is in the taskbar
only the child window gets visible,but the application window doesn't come into view. I want to know how to show both the windows when I select it from taskbar.

childwindow is also a winform,whose toplevel property is set as true,apart from it nothing
is new(JUST BY CLICKING A BUTTON OR CELL IN GRID I CREATE AN OBJECT FOR THE FORM AND USES IT SHOW PROPERTY TO SHOW)

```
 AlertMsgWindow _alertMsg;
    void dataGridViewAlerts_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.dataGridViewAlerts.getValue(0, this.dataGridViewAlerts.SelectedRow)))
            {
                this.dataGridViewAlerts.setCellImage(0, this.dataGridViewAlerts.SelectedRow, "NewsIconRead");

                if (_alertMsg == null || _alertMsg.IsDisposed)
                {
                    if (_alertMsg != null)
                    {
                        _alertMsg.onDeleteMessageRequest -= new DeleteMessage(_alertMsg_onDeleteMessageRequest);
                        _alertMsg.Dispose();
                    }
                    _alertMsg = new AlertMsgWindow();
                    _alertMsg.onDeleteMessageRequest += new DeleteMessage(_alertMsg_onDeleteMessageRequest);                       
                }

                _alertMsg.FillDetails(alertDetails[IDcollection[this.dataGridViewAlerts.SelectedRow]]);
                if (!_alertMsg.Visible)
                {                        
                    _alertMsg.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(this.Width / 4, -this.Height));                        
                    _alertMsg.Show(this);
                }

                if (onReadMessageReq != null)
                    onReadMessageReq(IDcollection[this.dataGridViewAlerts.SelectedRow]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

**Note: THIS IS HAPPENING ONLY IN WINDOWS2000**

I used a component named Dotnetmagic.dll,i dont know whether it causes the problem.can somebody helps me to solve this

Comment: I think this will depend a bit on *how* you show the child window. Can you share some code showing how that is done?

Comment: Upgrade the machine, this is not worth your time.  Or ours.

Answer (score 1):

```
I replaced these lines
```

_alertMsg.Location = PointToScreen(new Point(this.Width / 4, -this.Height));
With

_alertMsg.Left = x;
_alertMsg.Top = y;

and it solved my problem